# jython open a zip file and read its content

Tags: file-io, jython

I'm trying to open a zip file with jython using FileInputStream and ZipInputStream. But I'm strangely getting an FileNotFoundException when FileInputStream is called.

Here is my code:

```
from java.lang import System
from java.io import ObjectInputStream, FileInputStream, BufferedInputStream
from java.util.zip import ZipInputStream, ZipEntry


file_input_stream = FileInputStream('C:\\Documents and Settings\\usr\\My Documents\\Downloads\\test.zip')
zip_input_stream = ZipInputStream(BufferedInputStream(file_input_stream))

entry = zip_input_stream.getNextEntry()
entry = zip_input_stream.getNextEntry()

object_input_stream = ObjectInputStream(zip_input_stream)
graph.model = object_input_stream.readObject()

object_input_stream.close()
zip_input_stream.close()
file_input_stream.close()
```

My error is :

```
file_input_stream = FileInputStream('C:\\Documents and Settings\\usr\\My Documents\\Downloads\\test.zip')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
FileNotFoundException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Documents and Settings\usr\My Documents\Downloads\test.zip (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

I know for sure that the file is in the correct directory, if I call FileInputStream with a non-zip file, it works. What am I doing wrong here?

thanks

Comment: This isn't by any chance an issue caused by not showing file extensions, is it?  Do you, or do you not, show file extensions in explorer?

Comment: @Wug i can see the extension fine for this zip file, but not all files in explorer have their file extension visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open any folder in windows explorer.  If you're using windows 7 or Vista, press alt to view the menu bar (on XP it should already be visible).  Pick Tools -> Folder Options.  In the view tab, search in the box for a checkbox labeled "Hide extensions for known file types" and uncheck it.

On that note, the file is probably called "test.zip.zip", which would be why "test.zip" is not found.

Answer (score 0):

You know that you could use the [Python zipfile](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html) library for this, in your Jython code.

Comment: His shell isn't showing file extensions, so the file is actually called test.zip.zip.

Comment: I don't doubt you. Just suggesting that simpler code could be written using the Python lib than the Java API.